# Outputting a 2^n x 2^n matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I've written a simple program in Python which does the following:

**Input:** an integer \$n\$

**Output:** a \$2^n x 2^n\$ matrix containing small \$L\$s which fill the entire matrix except one single square. Each L has its unique number, and consists of three squares.

It's a fairly simple program, and you can see clearly what it does by typing in a few different \$n\$s.

**What I'd like to do:** Keep the actual algorithm as it is now (the `rec()` function), but improve my C-like code to make full use of Python's features.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, math

ur = [[1,0],
      [1,1]]

ul = [[0,1],
      [1,1]]

lr = [[1,1],
      [1,0]]

ll = [[1,1],
      [0,1]]

shapeCounter = 1

matrix = []

def printMatrix():
    for row in matrix:
        for element in row:
            if(element >= 10):
                print("%d" % element),
            else:
                print(" %d" % element),
        print
    print

def square(n):
    global matrix
    matrix = [[0]*(2**n) for x in xrange(2**n)]
    matrix[0][len(matrix) - 1] = -1
    rec(0, 0, len(matrix) - 1, len(matrix) - 1)
    matrix[0][len(matrix) - 1] = 0
    printMatrix()

def writeRect(rect, x, y):
    global shapeCounter
    matrix[y][x] += rect[0][0] * shapeCounter
    matrix[y+1][x] += rect[1][0] * shapeCounter
    matrix[y][x+1] += rect[0][1] * shapeCounter
    matrix[y+1][x+1] += rect[1][1] * shapeCounter
    shapeCounter += 1

def rec(sx, sy, 
        ex, ey):
    if(ex - sx < 1 or ey - sy < 1):
        return
    #print("(%d,%d) (%d,%d)" %(sx,sy,ex,ey))

    if(matrix[sy][sx] != 0):
        rect = ul
    elif(matrix[ey][sx] != 0):
        rect = ll
    elif(matrix[sy][ex] != 0):
        rect = ur
    elif(matrix[ey][ex] != 0):
        rect = lr

    hx = sx + (ex - sx) / 2
    hy = sy + (ey - sy) / 2

    writeRect(rect, hx, hy)

    rec(sx, sy, hx, hy)
    rec(hx + 1, sy, ex, hy)
    rec(sx, hy + 1, hx, ey)
    rec(hx + 1, hy + 1, ex, ey)

if __name__=='__main__':
    square(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: Get out of the habit of using global variables like that. You're just asking for trouble when you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, math

ur = [[1,0],
      [1,1]]

ul = [[0,1],
      [1,1]]

lr = [[1,1],
      [1,0]]

ll = [[1,1],
      [0,1]]
```

Rather then creating four separate variables, I'd suggest making a list. I'd also suggest using the `numpy` library for its array type. It makes working with 2D arrays much nicer then using lists of lists.

```
shapeCounter = 1

matrix = []
```

Don't use global variables. Instead, pass matrix in as the parameter to the function.

```
def printMatrix():
    for row in matrix:
        for element in row:
            if(element >= 10):
```

Parens aren't needed here

```
                print("%d" % element),
            else:
                print(" %d" % element),
        print
    print
```

Note that if you used `numpy`, that library would already be able to nicely print a matrix.

```
def square(n):
    global matrix
```

This function should really create and return the matrix

```
    matrix = [[0]*(2**n) for x in xrange(2**n)]
```

In numpy, this would be `matrix = numpy.zeros( (2**n, 2**n) )`

```
    matrix[0][len(matrix) - 1] = -1
    rec(0, 0, len(matrix) - 1, len(matrix) - 1)
    matrix[0][len(matrix) - 1] = 0
    printMatrix()
```

Functions that do work on your variables shouldn't print them. Your main control function should do the printing.

```
def writeRect(rect, x, y):
    global shapeCounter
```

This isn't a terrible use of a global, but I'd avoid it. I'd have an object this attribute was stored on.

```
    matrix[y][x] += rect[0][0] * shapeCounter
    matrix[y+1][x] += rect[1][0] * shapeCounter
    matrix[y][x+1] += rect[0][1] * shapeCounter
    matrix[y+1][x+1] += rect[1][1] * shapeCounter
    shapeCounter += 1

def rec(sx, sy, 
        ex, ey):
```

I wouldn't use abbreviations. Use `start_x`, `end_y` to make your code clearer.

```
    if(ex - sx < 1 or ey - sy < 1):
        return
    #print("(%d,%d) (%d,%d)" %(sx,sy,ex,ey))

    if(matrix[sy][sx] != 0):
        rect = ul
    elif(matrix[ey][sx] != 0):
        rect = ll
    elif(matrix[sy][ex] != 0):
        rect = ur
    elif(matrix[ey][ex] != 0):
        rect = lr
```

You don't need all those parens

```
    hx = sx + (ex - sx) / 2
    hy = sy + (ey - sy) / 2

    writeRect(rect, hx, hy)

    rec(sx, sy, hx, hy)
    rec(hx + 1, sy, ex, hy)
    rec(sx, hy + 1, hx, ey)
    rec(hx + 1, hy + 1, ex, ey)

if __name__=='__main__':
    square(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: In newer versions of python, print is deprecated as a keyword and requires brackets like any other function.

Comment: @Aleksandar, when I said the parens are unnecessary, I'm referring to the if statement, not print.

Comment: Your code view segment shows print, that's what led me to my conclusion. :)

Comment: You'll see that may comments are always after the code they are commenting on, not before. But I might still object to the usage here for being inconsistent.